# Не вижу ошибку в коде к задаче егэ

Tags: python

30. Имеется набор данных, состоящий из троек положительных целых чисел. Необходимо выбрать из каждой тройки ровно одно число так, чтобы сумма всех выбранных чисел не делилась на 7 и при этом была минимально возможной. Гарантируется, что искомую сумму получить можно. Программа должна напечатать одно число – минимально возможную сумму, соответствующую условиям задачи.

Пример входного файла:

6
8 3 4
4 8 12
9 8 11
2 8 3
12 3 5
1 4 11
Для указанных входных данных значением искомой суммы должно быть число 22.
Мой код :

```
with open('27.txt') as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    lst = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        line = line.replace(' ', '')
    
        x = int(line[0])
        y = int(line[1])
        z = int(line[2])
        lst.append((x, y, z))

print(lst)

def solve(lst):
    min_sum = 0
    max_diff = -1e300
    for triplet in lst:
        min_sum += min(triplet)
        diff = abs(triplet[0] - triplet[1] - triplet[2])
        if diff % 7 != 0:
            max_diff = max(max_diff, diff)
    if min_sum % 7 != 0:
        return(min_sum)
    else:
        return(min_sum - max_diff)
print(solve(lst))
```

Comment: Во-первых, непонятно, надо вывести одно число (вроде так сказано в условии?) или по числу для каждой тройки? Во-вторых, почему задача 30, а файл ты читаешь 27? И в-третьих, а что не работает-то?

Comment: Вывести минимальную сумму. Файл тот, проверил. Выводит неверный ответ, непонятно, как починить

Comment: Что-то непонятное считается для diff

Comment: вот тут: `line = line.replace(' ', '') x = int(line[0])`видимо пропущено `line = line.split()`